# Rich text area field on VF whille rendering as PDF

Tags: visualforce, pdf, rerender, richtextarea

I am using an rich text type field on VF page and that page is rendering as PDF.
My concern is, I am not able to wrap the content of the field.
I am using :

```
<apex:outputtext value="{!accObj.Rich_text__c}" escape="false"/>
```

Its coming out of the page.

Thanks

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap"

Answer (score 4):

Try using `<apex:outputField>` instead of `<apex:outPutText>` and see if that solves your issue. You could also wrap this in an Table and TD